# Current date in doxygen documentation C++ header

Tags: c++, doxygen

I wonder if it is possible to use the current date when documenting a C++ function with doxygen. For example

```
/**
 * This function is really boring. Documentation generated on __DATE__ 
 */
void f()
{}
```

Is there such a command? The __ DATE __ C++ macro doesn't work as it is inside a comment, so the pre-processor does not expand it. I can use a LaTeX macro such as `\f$\mathrm{\today}\f$` but it looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a [custom command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html) for that… let it be `\today` for example :)

Unfortunately there is no builtin command to get a current date (it is available only for HTML header/footer templates as `$date` variable). But if you have (use) a build system (like CMake, autotools & etc), you may generate the `Doxyfile` (from, say `Doxyfile.in`) and render a current date. E.g. something like this

```
ALIASES += today="@TODAY@"
```

so `@TODAY@` will be replaced w/ actual date of build.

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that I can make an alias to `\f$\mathrm{\today}\f$`? That will work, however in the generated pdf it produces the date without a space in between (that's why I said it's ugly), like: October25, 2014. Is there any other way to get the system date?